# Is it ok to have Static Class for SQL Queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, static

I'm just exploring/crafting a ticked based service desk software on C#. That connects MS SQL database for the datas. ***So:***

- I've made a static class named as dbFunctions (names given for the sake of the example)
- I've dbLogin(), dbGetSomething1(parameter), dbGetSomething2() and few more methods in it.

With this I don't need to instantiate the class everytime. I can remove the "static" and instantiate the class to use its methods as well too. But I do have more than 10 winforms that will require to use this methods.

Is there a good alternative to using static classes?

Comment: That entirely depends on what the methods do, and how they're used. There's nothing inherently bad about using static methods, so asking the question without seeing the code is impossible to answer. Nevertheless, this question is asking for opinions, which is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Codes are basic ADO queries made within System.Data.SqlClient. They just send queries against the database and return the results to where it's called. Nothing out of ordinary. @Rob

Comment: I use "Using" for that and I do close connections asap. @GrantWinney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to strongly consider with static methods is that *you tie yourself to that dependency*.  So if you can live with that coupling you're OK.  I would, however, make sure you have some layer of encapsulation so that you can test other parts of your app without being dependent of the database functions.

For example, you may have interfaces to define your data layer that are implemented by classes that call the static methods within them, but having the UI or business layer call the static methods makes it much more difficult to test those independently, or to swap out a different data layer later if desired (which is far less common but not unheard of).

Comment: Thank you. I'm not that used to programming but I see what do you mean. I'll consider this information whilist doing the rest. I've also used some encapsulation as well. I feel like, I should complete this app with least amount text/code in it. Maybe my approach is wrong.

Comment: Well, _less_ code is not always _better_ code.  Get something that _works_, then make it _better_, that may mean reducing repetitive code, decoupling layers (which is typically _more_ code), etc.